# Readable procedure not getting called when pipe has info

Tags: linux, file, pipe, tcl, event-driven

On linux I created a pipe file using 'mkfifo pip'.  On one terminal, I issue 'tail -f pip' and in other I issue 'ls > pip'.  I could see the information flow from second terminal to the first one.

I created a TCL script to read the information that is flowing into the pip.

```
fconfigure stdout -buffering none
set fd [open "pip"]
fconfigure $fd -blocking 0 -buffering line
fileevent $fd readable [list Treading $fd]

proc Treading {desc} {
        gets $desc line
        puts stdout "Got line - $line"
}

while {1} {
        puts "waiting..."
        after 2000
}
```

I ran the program and issue 'cat > pip' from another terminal, in the output I am not seeing any 'Got line' prints called from Treading procedure.

```
$tclsh sockpip.tcl 
waiting...
waiting...
waiting...
waiting...
waiting...
waiting...
```

Can someone please help me clarify, if I am missing something.  I want to have event-driven programming working.

Thanks in advance.
uv.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  But my requirement is, after I create fileevent, I should continue doing some other tasks(i think using 'after' was my bad idea).  The fileevent should happen when some change happens in the file.
Can someone help with this requirement

Answer (score 2):

For the `readable` event to fire, you need to use the non-blocking form of `after`, see https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/after.htm#M6 and you need to start the Tcl event loop.  Instead of:

```
while {1} {
        puts "waiting..."
        after 2000
}
```

Try:

```
proc waiting {} {
        puts "waiting..."
        after 2000 waiting
}

waiting
vwait forever
```

Answer (score 2):

The key problem is you're using a blocking `after`. Tcl interpreters are *strictly* single-threaded, and the event loop is only serviced when you call `vwait` or `update` (or something else that wraps those or calls `Tcl_DoOneEvent()` in Tcl's C API). Calling those recursively is not recommended because you can get into a mess with reentrant callbacks, and [you don't want that](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/Update+considered+harmful).

However, you can do a loop using a coroutine and a non-blocking `after`, like this:

```
proc snooze {delay} {
    after $delay [info coroutine]
    yield
}

coroutine MyWaitLoop apply {{} {
    while {1} {
        puts "waiting..."
        snooze 2000
    }
}}

vwait forever;  # Run the event loop until you stop it
```

Because this is waiting in the event loop, handlers for the pipe will be called.